# Grid rows created by grid-auto-rows don't stretch the parent

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to make a flexible layout that stretches for additional content added.

```css
.parent {
  min-height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr;
}

.child {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
}


.header {
  background: yellow;
}

.content {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border: 1px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="header"></div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to avoid explicitly stating the height of each content div. If i use `grid-auto-rows: 400px`, it creates a row with 400px height for each content div and parent stretches to fit all content divs. Like it should.

But if I use `grid-auto-rows: 100%`, it creates rows with the height equal to 100% of the child's height each, while the parent doesn't stretch.

Is there a way to avoid that and make the parent grow to fit all content inside without explicitly stating the height of each in the child?

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows. Guess you're looking for something like `minmax` or `fit-content`

Comment: Not really. From what i've understood, <pre>minmax</pre> and <pre>fit-content</pre> allows an item to take space between to sizes or up to some size. While i want to make the child element with height equal to part of the parent's initial height and then grow, making parent bigger as well. So if the child grows(more content is added), then the parent grows as well. But the child's inital size(and space for each part of content) is set by it's parent.

Answer (score 2):

> But if i use grid-auto-rows: 100%, it creates rows with height equal to 100% of child's height each, while parent doesn't stretch.

It's more complex than this. Setting `100%` means that the row will be 100% of the `child` height which is defined to be `1fr` inside the parent thus it's `400px`. So the height of the each row should be `400px` and having more than one row will create an overflow since the height of `child` is also `400px`.

In other words, you have defined the size of **one row** to be equal to the height of your element thus more than one row will for sure create an overflow.

One idea of fix is to consider `1fr` within `grid-auto-rows` which will make all the `content` to have the same height and if one of them will grow all will grow the same stretching the `child` and `parent` element.

Setting a height for one of them:

```css
.parent {
  min-height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr;
}

.child {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  border: 1px solid;
}


.header {
  background: yellow;
}

.content {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border: 1px dashed blue;
}

.content:nth-child(2) {
  height:300px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="header"></div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Adding content:

```css
.parent {
  min-height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr;
}

.child {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  border: 1px solid;
}


.header {
  background: yellow;
}

.content {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border: 1px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="header"></div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content">
    lorem ipsum<br>lorem ipsum<br>lorem ipsum<br>lorem ipsum<br>lorem ipsum<br>lorem ipsum<br>lorem ipsum<br>lorem ipsum<br>lorem ipsum<br>lorem ipsum<br>lorem ipsum<br>lorem ipsum<br>lorem ipsum<br>lorem ipsum<br>
    </div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also set a `min-height` to any of the child element to create a lower bound:

```css
.parent {
  min-height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr;
}

.child {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  border: 1px solid;
}


.header {
  background: yellow;
}

.content {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border: 1px dashed blue;
}
.content:last-child {
  min-height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="header"></div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Increasing the parent height will also make the content to expand:

```css
.parent {
  min-height: 900px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr;
}

.child {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  border: 1px solid;
}


.header {
  background: yellow;
}

.content {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border: 1px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="header"></div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Based on your requirement in the comments here is a *hack* that will do what you want:

```css
.parent {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px;
  grid-auto-rows: 300px; /*this will define the child height*/
}

.child {
  display: grid;
  border: 1px solid;
  display:contents; /*use this to cross the child and make content grid element*/
}


.header {
  background: yellow;
}

.content {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border: 1px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="header"></div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I used `display:contents` to make the child part of the grid then I defined explicetly the height of each one inside the parent instead of the `min-height`

Comment: My thought was to create independent child element, which contains some content of equal size. When more content is added, child get's bigger, adding new rows.
While parent sets the amount of space child will take. So if parent's min-height is 500px, 100px for header and 400 for child, child should be 400px for each piece of content. 2 pieces of content - 100px header, 800px child and 900px parent. But looks like it's too much responsibility for a parent element.
Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @BlackDrake it's not about *responsibility* but you are thinking in a cycle. If you read your comment again you notice that you said *parent will define* then *child will expand* --> both cannot work because you will have a cycle (like explained in my answer). Either the parent will define something used later OR the child will defined the parent height based on their content. Having both using this configuration is somehow impossible.

Comment: @BlackDrake check the update, I added a solution that is close to what you want

Comment: It's not entirely a cycle, but yeah, i just was hoping that there is a way to create aditional rows based on min-height, while also expanding the parent's current height.
Your solution after update mostly makes it work, but it works kinda strange(why first content div has 0 height?) and acts like there is no "child" elements.
Nevertheless, thank your for answer. It really helped me to understand what's going on and how to find a solution.

Comment: @BlackDrake forget to remove the 1fr (the issue for the first content), fixed. And yes it acts like there is no child item which is the purpose of `display:contents`. The idea is to keep the html but simulate all the content as a part of the grid so they can get affected by the height defined in the parent (https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents)

Answer (score 1):

Setting 100% to the *inner grid* will force it to occupy all the space in the *outer grid item* and cause *overflow*. You should be setting 400px *explicity* to it (in that case, the *outer grid item* will expand)

You can set `grid-template-rows: 100px minmax(400px, 1fr)` instead of setting `min-height` on the *outer grid*, and `grid-auto-rows: 400px` to the *inner grid*. To make it simpler you can use [`CSS variables`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables):

```css
:root {
  --h: 400px;
}
.parent {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px minmax(var(--h), 1fr);
}
.child {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: var(--h);
  border: 1px solid;
}
.header {
  background: yellow;
}
.content {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border: 1px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="header"></div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: setting the minmax is probably useless in this case because the fr will always win since at least one content will be 400px so it will be >=400px in all the cases.

Comment: it's not useless, see `min-height` is not kept in `parent`... check the height of `content` in the above snippet - it *is* 400px... and the whole setup works for the OP's requirement, so that should not be a problem :)

Comment: I meant if you replace the minmax with only `1fr` you will also get the same result because your content is 400px

Comment: `grid-template-rows: 100px minmax(400px, 1fr)` ensures that *even if* the inner grid changes the second row of the *outer grid* will be at least 400px... that's why :)

Comment: Thanks. My goal was to prevent child depending on the parent's size. So if i make parent's height 800px, child will adjust. For me it's really confusing why 100% causes overflow, while pixels work fine.

Comment: `grid-auto-rows: 100%` means each items will be place in the row with 100% height, one `content` itself fills the 100% space and then onwards overflow will happen...

Comment: Yeah, but if 100% = 400px, 400px should take 100% space as well.

Comment: Nope, 100% would be 400px because your `header` is 100px and `min-height: 500px` comes into play and then 1fr would be 400px... But specifying 400px for`content` explicitly means the second row height will  stretch...